# Load hundreds of fonts dynamically using JS with low manual work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, fonts

I have a folder `/assets/fonts` with several hundred fonts I want to use on a website dynamically. User will specify which one to use. Kinda like in a text editor.

Specifying `font-face` for each and every font manually makes no sense, because it would take me hours.

What procedure should I take to make all the fonts ready to be used?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("select").on("change",function(){
   $("h1").css("font-family",$(this).find("option:selected").val());
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
 <option >select font</option>
 <option value="Tangerine">Tangerine</option>
 <option value="Inconsolata">Inconsolata</option>
 <option value="Roboto">Roboto</option>
</select>
<br>
<h1>google Font<h1>
```

---

> used local Font in css

```
  @font-face {
      font-family: 'MyWebFont';
      src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
           url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
           url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```